# segmentation fault when I take in the first value of matrix

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

If I run my program, and When I typed the dimensions of matrix, after I typed the first value of matrix , the console write out: Segmentation fault

**For example**:

```
4

3
```

Segmentation fault
Process returned 139(0x8B)

```
void inMatrix(int n, double **matrix)
{
    int j, i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j= 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            scanf("%lf", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void inVector(double *vektor, int n)
{
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        scanf("%lf", &vektor[k]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    // read dimension of matrix and value
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //matrix
    double** matrix = (double **) calloc(n, sizeof ( double*));
    //vector
    double* vector = (double *) calloc(n, sizeof ( double));

    // read values of matrix
    inMatrix(n, matrix);
    // read values of vector
    inVector(vector, n);

    outVector(vector, n);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in the matrix you only allocate memory for the pointers, and not for the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't allocate memory for the elements of the matrix, only for the pointers to the individual lines.

You need something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    matrix[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(double));
```

Of course, you must free stuff in the same manner when you're done with it.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    free(matrix[i]);

free(matrix);
```

Comment: Oh my god it's to hard for me. I've done it, but at the 5th element of value write out again the segmentation fault (if my matix is 4 dim)
`for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
       {
          matrix[k] = (double *) calloc(n, sizeof ( double));
        // read values of matrix
            inMatrix(n, matrix);
        // read values of vector
            inVector(vector, n);

            outVector(vector, n);
            printf("\n");
        free(matrix[k]);`

Comment: You cannot read more than you allocate. Maybe you need the matrix to be 5x5 instead of 4x4 ?

Comment: yes, I need nxn matrix, sometimes 3x3, 4x4, or, it is variable (homework)